# How to I go from a String to an Array

Tags: java

I want to change my strings into array lists in my scanner program. I know that I have to use the .split method, but I am not sure how. I will use this example:

This is a good class with JAVA -> [This, is, a, good, class, with, Java]

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
public class scanner_LAB {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a sentance with the word \"java\" in it: ");
        
        // input and end program
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Done - Press enter key to end program");
        String line = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        
        // length
        int length = line.length();
        System.out.println("Your sent " + length);
        
        // upper case and lower case 
        String lowerCase = line.toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(lowerCase);
        
        String upperCase = line.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println(upperCase);
        System.out.println(lowerCase.indexOf("java"));
        
        // java to Java
        System.out.println(line.substring(0,line.toLowerCase().indexOf("java")) + "Java" + line.substring(line.toLowerCase().indexOf("java")+4, line.length()));
        
        // java to JAVA
        System.out.println(line.substring(0,line.toLowerCase().indexOf("java")) + "JAVA" + line.substring(line.toLowerCase().indexOf("java")+4, line.length()));
        
        // string to arrays
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: line.slpit(...) is the way to go!

Comment: Using line.split(" ") will split your line at every space (" ") and return you an array with which you can do whatever you like

Answer (score 1):

You can use the split function of string to split the string into array.

```
String[] strArray = line.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about using the split method, this is the general way to use it
// string to arrays
String[] words = line.split(" ");
for(String word: words)
System.out.println(word);

I ran your code and this works four your intended purpose (I've just commented out some of your code that wasn't related to this question)

```
import java.util.*;
public class scanner_LAB {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a sentance with the word \"java\" in it: ");
    
    // input and end program
    //System.out.println();
    //System.out.println("Done - Press enter key to end program");
    String line = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);
    
    // length
    int length = line.length();
    System.out.println("Your sent " + length);
    
    // upper case and lower case 
    String lowerCase = line.toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(lowerCase);
    
    String upperCase = line.toUpperCase();
    System.out.println(upperCase);
    System.out.println(lowerCase.indexOf("java"));
    
    // java to Java
    //System.out.println(line.substring(0,line.toLowerCase().indexOf("java")) + "Java" + line.substring(line.toLowerCase().indexOf("java")+4, line.length()));
    
    // java to JAVA
    //System.out.println(line.substring(0,line.toLowerCase().indexOf("java")) + "JAVA" + line.substring(line.toLowerCase().indexOf("java")+4, line.length()));
    
    // string to arrays
    String[] words = line.split(" ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(words));
    
}
```

}

Comment: how would I make it so that when printed, the output would be in a list like, for example:  

going from:
This is a good class with Java 

to:
[This, is, a, good, class, with, Java]

Comment: Using the Arrays.asList() method. Eg. System.out.println(Arrays.asList(words));

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect this change 